# Reduce in built fan noise from Netgear POE switch?

Tags: networking, fan

Ive got a Netgear GS724TPv2 switch. It is powering 4 POE access points (Ubiqutiy) and about 12 network devices.

The rack is sitting at about 34 deg C.

The fan on it seems to be running at full speed, and ive got a noise complaint from the occupier of the building.

Is it possible to change the settings on the switch to run the fan at a lower temp ?

I was thinking of swapping out the switch for a non POE switch and powering the access points via POE injectors, but this seems like overkill.

Answer (score 5):

We have 3 of the 48 port variant of the switch in question and these have the same issue with the noise levels, in our case this is not a problem as the office space can be noisy itself and is not noticeable by users.

I believe the only way to reduce the noise is to manually swap the fans out with a similar size. (This could be costly as small fans are generally noisy.)

On the article below a user has modified the case of the switch to fit a 120mm fan which operates with much lower noise levels (Second before last comment/reply.)

https://community.netgear.com/t5/Smart-Plus-Click-Switches/GS748TP-Fan-Speed-Control/td-p/455458

Answer (score 1):

The fans will run slower with a lower voltage, so if you really want a quick fix then you could try and reduce the speed using a resistor in series with the fans (any terminal). However, this is bad practise, and will obviously increase temperatures so you may want to look for passive techniques, like using foam to dampen the noise inside the switch if there is space.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut the noise in a few ways that all have pros and cons.

- Cut the noise with sound reflecting/absorbing materials being careful not to insulate the equipment and raise the heat
- Reduce the fan noise by replacing or modifying the fan
- Reduce the heat buildup in the rack by adding additional air circulation (bigger, thus slower and quieter fans, more space between things, etc)
- Reduce the heat generation in the rack by moving to external injectors or relocating other equipment using power

I'd probably go for an open cell foam winding "chimney" and a fan underneath drawing in cooler air.  (unless the room is 34C...)